# Url rewriting/routing and webapi

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am designing a theme based website using webapi. I have saved my themes in folders `A, B` and `C`. The themes are actual html pages that fetch some content( like photos) etc. from database depending upon the client.

So my actual pages are like: `localhost/A/index.html?client=Client1` (where A is the theme name).

I want to show the url to user as `localhost/client1/index.html`. I can fetch the theme name from client's id ( `client1` in the example).

- What combination of routing and url rewriting should I use to accomplish this?
  I am hosting in IIS? And how should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could have the following custom route:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "CustomRoute",
        routeTemplate: "api/{client}/index.html",
        defaults: new { controller = "values" }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

and the corresponding API controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET /api/{client}/index.html
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string client)
    {
        // The client variable will represent the value
        // that was passed in the route segment
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, client);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it got me started. Queries like "http://localhost/api/client1/index.html" are now redirected to the get function of controller. So I can deduce my theme name "A" inside the get function. But how then do I get redirected to this page - localhost/A/index.html?client=Client1. ( Obviously not displaying this to user).